# Can I set a sequence of bits without unsetting the previous values?

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I've got a sequence of bits, say

```
0110 [1011] 1111
```

Let's say I want to set that myddle nybble to `0111` as the new value.

Using a positional masking approach with `AND` or `OR`, I seem to have no choice but to first unset the original value to `0000`, because if I trying `AND`ing or `OR`ing against that original value of `1011`, I'm not going to come out with the desired result of `0111`.

Is there another logical operator I should be using to get the desired effect? Or am I locked into 2 operations every time?

---

The result after kindly assistance was:

```
inline void foo(Clazz* parent, const Uint8& material, const bool& x, const bool& y, const bool& z)
{
    Uint8 offset = x | (y << 1) | (z << 2); //(0-7)
    Uint64 positionMask = 255 << offset * 8; //255 = length of each entry (8 bits), 8 = number of bits per material entry
    Uint64 value = material << offset * 8;
    parent->childType &= ~positionMask; //flip bits to clear given range.
    parent->childType |= value;
}
```

...I'm sure this will see further improvement, but this is the (semi-)readable version.

Comment: Is your concern with what you do in the source code, or what object code will be generated? `std::vector<bool>` or `std::bitset` (for a couple possibilities) will let you directly manipulate bits at the source code level, but it'll be translated to roughly the operations you've outlined in the object code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you happen to already know the current values of the bits, you can XOR:

```
  0110 1011 1111
^ 0000 1100 0000

= 0110 0111 1111
```

(where the `1100` needs to be computed first as the XOR between the current bits and the desired bits).

This is, of course, still 2 operations.  The difference is that you could precompute the first XOR in certain circumstances.

Other than this special case, there is no other way.  You fundamentally need to represent 3 states: set to 1, set to 0, don't change.  You can't do this with a single binary operand.

Comment: @Nick: So if you already know that your start value is `????1011????`, and that you need to get to `????1100????`, you first compute `000010110000 ^ 000011000000` to get you a "mask".  You then apply this mask by XORing.  In general, not very useful.  In specific cases (where you know before and after values at, say, compile-time), it only takes 1 operation.

Comment: Yep, sorry didn't get your edit till after I'd written that comment, then saw your edit and deleted my comment. No worries. I appreciate the suggestion -- in my case,  there is no possibility of knowing the XOR mask beforehand. It's a good trick to have up the sleeve, though! Accepting this as the implicit reply is, "It will take 2 ops."

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use bit fields (and perhaps unions if you want to be able to access your structure as a set of bit fields and as an int at the same time) , something along the lines of:

```
struct foo
{  
unsigned int o1:4;  
unsigned int o2:4;  
unsigned int o3:4;   
};  

foo bar;  

bar.o2 = 0b0111;
```

Not sure if it translates into more efficient machine code than your clear/set...

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's an assembly instruction in MMIX for this:

```
SETL $1, 0x06BF ; 0110 1011 1111
SETL $2, 0x0070 ; 0000 0111 0000
SETL rM, 0x00F0 ; set mask register

MUX $1,$2,$1 ; result is 0110 0111 1111
```

But in C++ here's what you're probably thinking of as 'unsetting the previous value'.

```
int S = 0x6BF;      // starting value:   0110 1011 1111
int M = 0x0F0;      // value mask:       0000 1111 0000
int V = 0x070;      // value:            0000 0111 0000

int N = (S&~M) | V; // new value:        0110 0111 1111
```

But since the intermediate result 0110 0000 1111 from `(S&~M)` is never stored in a variable anywhere I wouldn't really call it 'unsetting' anything. It's just a bitwise boolean expression. Any boolean expression with the same truth table will work. Here's another one:

```
N = ((S^V) & M) ^ A; // corresponds to Oli Charlesworth's answer
```

The related truth tables:

```
    S M V  (S& ~M) | V      ((S^V) & M) ^ S
    0 0 0    0 1   0           0   0    0
 *  0 0 1    0 1   1           1   0    0
    0 1 0    0 0   0           0   0    0
    0 1 1    0 0   1           1   1    1
    1 0 0    1 1   1           1   0    1
 *  1 0 1    1 1   1           0   0    1
    1 1 0    0 0   0           1   1    0
    1 1 1    0 0   1           0   0    1
                   ^                    ^
                   |____________________|
```

The rows marked with '*' don't matter because they won't occur (a bit in V will never be set when the corresponding mask bit is not set). Except for those rows, the truth tables for the expressions are the same.

Comment: I got all excited there, and then discovered what MMIX was. You joker, you.